# OpenGL ES Green Screen... But I want to use black

Tags: ios, opengl-es, fragment-shader

This works great for green screen, my background is green and using this code it makes green = alpha.

```
lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(u_samplers2D[0], vTextu);

lowp float rbAverage = textureColor.r * 0.5 + textureColor.b * 0.5;
lowp float gDelta = textureColor.g - rbAverage;
textureColor.a = 1.0 - smoothstep(0.0, 0.25, gDelta);
textureColor.a = textureColor.a * textureColor.a * textureColor.a;
gl_FragColor = textureColor;
```

How do I change the code so that it use a black background instead of green? I'm thinking I could get values for the dark red, green, blues then use that as the alpha? Any pointers would be kind.

Comment: Am I right in that with this computation the minimum alpha you can achieve (i.e. for pure green) would be `0.42`? Strange, since I would expect pure green to be completely transparent (i.e. give an alpha of `0`). This minimum alpha would already be achieved for yellow and even orange. So I have strong doubt in this being a good color key function in the first place.

Comment: You could try to just set alpha on dark pixels, it might work, but will not be as good as chroma key unless you can guarantee that foreground is lit.

Comment: Thank Vasaka, sounds like an idea. How would I do that? (still learning about the shader language).

Comment: @IanClay posted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(u_samplers2D, vTextu);
lowp float gtemp =  smoothstep(0.0, 0.5, textureColor.r);
gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, gtemp);
```

This works for my situation. I was using a greyscale image with black background and just needed the white elements. The problem I had was that I was applying the alpha to grey pixels, but now Im using white and applying the alpha to that. I can adjust the smoothstep values to change the effect. And also add another alpha to fade in or out the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate how close value to black, simplest way is to take maximum of the r g and b values, then set some threshold when you consider color opaque, and map your alpha values to [0..1] in pseudo code:

```
float brightness = max(textureColor.r, textureColor.g, textureColor.b);
float threshold = 0.1;
float alpha = brightness > threshold ? 1 : (threshold - brightness) / threshold;
gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb, alpha);
```

Comment: Huh, how would that help? What he want's to do is use a black as transparency key instead of green, as his current code does.

Comment: @ChristianRau misunderstood the question, fixed the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Vasaka I will try your idea, wasn't sure how to use max as from what I've read it only takes 2 values?

Comment: @IanClay just call it twice storing intermediate value, I wrote it like that to spare trivial details.